# How to copy conditional formatting when copying value within if check?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a check such as

```
=IF(A1="","",Sheet2!A1)
```

Where Sheet2!A1 contains a conditional formatted cell (colored a specific color)

I want to keep the color on my new sheet

How can I copy the cell, its value and its formatting?

Can this be accomplished within a formula or is there something in VBA I can write that will do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Can this be accomplished within a formula?
```

AFAIK, I don't think you can do this using excel formula

### VBA Code:

Select the cell where you had the formula and run the macro

```
Sub ColorCopyCell()
If (IsEmpty(ActiveCell)) Then 'If empty
Worksheets(2).Range(ActiveCell.Address).Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
End If
End Sub
```